# tinymce removed breaks in codesample plugin

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, tinymce

I am working on a project where I using tinymce with the codesample plugin.
When I am set up some code in the codesample every thing is fine but after I saved this code in the database and goes to the view page every thing is in one row. It looks like that all the breaks are removed.

I'm doing this project in Asp.net core mvc entity framework.

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#ArtikelInhoud',
            plugins: "code",
            plugins: 'codesample',
            codesample_languages: [
                { text: 'HTML/XML', value: 'markup' },
                { text: 'JavaScript', value: 'javascript' },
                { text: 'CSS', value: 'css' },
                { text: 'PHP', value: 'php' },
                { text: 'Ruby', value: 'ruby' },
                { text: 'Python', value: 'python' },
                { text: 'Java', value: 'java' },
                { text: 'C', value: 'c' },
                { text: 'C#', value: 'csharp' },
                { text: 'C++', value: 'cpp' }
            ],
            remove_linebreaks: false,
            convert_newlines_to_br: true,
            force_br_newlines: true
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the output html, could be a styling issue

Answer (score 0):

When you render content created with the `codesample` plugin you need to include some code from Prism when you do so. This is documented on the `codesample` plugin page:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/codesample/#usingprismjsonyourwebpage

> You need to add `prism.js` and `prism.css` to your page in order to get
>   the syntax highlighted code samples on your webpage (as created by the
>   Code Sample plugin). The Code Sample plugin uses the following
>   languages: markup, javascript, css, php, ruby, python, java, c, csharp
>   and cpp. You can generate the `prism.js` and `prism.css` files on the
>   download page at the Prism website.

Answer (score 0):

I did not successfully reproduce your problem, the following is a successful example, you can refer to it.

*(I hope you can provide the complete code, tell us how you submitted the data, and the corresponding js and css references.)*

Data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Content{ get; set; } 
}
```

controller:

```
   public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(Data data)
    {
       //save the content in data.Content to database
        return View(data);
    }
```

View:

```
    @model WebApplication_core_mvc.Models.Data
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    } 
   <h1>Test</h1>
    @section Scripts{ 
        <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=qagffr3pkuv17a8on1afax661irst1hbr4e6tbv888sz91jc" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
        <script>
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#ArtikelInhoud',
                plugins: "code",
                plugins: 'codesample',
                codesample_languages: [
                    { text: 'HTML/XML', value: 'markup' },
                    { text: 'JavaScript', value: 'javascript' },
                    { text: 'CSS', value: 'css' },
                    { text: 'PHP', value: 'php' },
                    { text: 'Ruby', value: 'ruby' },
                    { text: 'Python', value: 'python' },
                    { text: 'Java', value: 'java' },
                    { text: 'C', value: 'c' },
                    { text: 'C#', value: 'csharp' },
                    { text: 'C++', value: 'cpp' }
                ],
                remove_linebreaks: false,
                convert_newlines_to_br: true,
                force_br_newlines: true
            });
        </script>
    }

    <form asp-action="Test" method="post">
      <textarea id="ArtikelInhoud" asp-for="Content"> 
      </textarea>
      <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="button" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
```

Here is the result:

[image]